# What does this type declaration mean in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript and I'm reading over someone else's code and having trouble with this declaration:

```
    private somevar: { [s: string]: string };
```

What type is this? Square brackets indicate an array, but I'm confused about exactly what shape this would be in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an indexable type. Looking at this variable definition's type expression:

```
let myIndexVar: { [key: string]: number; };
```

- `: { ... }` means it's an object.
- `[key: string]: number;` is the index signature of the object.

Within the index signature:

- `[key: string]` defines the name of the key—`key`—and the type of the key—`string`.
- `: number;` is the type of the value—`number`.

These types are used like so:

```
let myIndexVar: { [key: string]: number; } = {};

myIndexVar["key"] = 4; // key is string, value is number
```

Note that you can give the key any name you like. Giving it a descriptive name is helpful to tell what the key is, though the variable name should also do that:

[image: Intellisense example]

Comment: It's worth noting that `key` can be any string, i.e. `myIndexVar["foobar"] = 37` would be a valid assignment too in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To further explain the answer by [David Sherret](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188246/david-sherret)

From the [Typscript docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

> Indexable Types Similarly to how we can use interfaces to describe function types, we can also describe types that we can “index into”
>   like a[10], or ageMap["daniel"]. Indexable types have an index
>   signature that describes the types we can use to index into the
>   object, along with the corresponding return types when indexing. Let’s
>   take an example:
>
> ```
> interface StringArray {
>     [index: number]: string;
> }
>
> let myArray: StringArray;
> myArray = ["Bob", "Fred"];
>
> let myStr: string = myArray[0];
> ```
>
> Above, we have a StringArray interface that has an index signature.
>   This index signature states that when a StringArray is indexed with a
>   number, it will return a string.
>
> There are two types of supported index signatures: string and number.
>   It is possible to support both types of indexers, but the type
>   returned from a numeric indexer must be a subtype of the type returned
>   from the string indexer. This is because when indexing with a number,
>   JavaScript will actually convert that to a string before indexing into
>   an object. That means that indexing with 100 (a number) is the same
>   thing as indexing with "100" (a string), so the two need to be
>   consistent.
>
> ```
> class Animal {
>     name: string;
> }
> class Dog extends Animal {
>     breed: string;
> }
>
> // Error: indexing with a 'string' will sometimes get you a Dog!
> interface NotOkay {
>     [x: number]: Animal;
>     [x: string]: Dog;
> }
> ```
>
> While string index signatures are a powerful way to describe the
>   “dictionary” pattern, they also enforce that all properties match
>   their return type. This is because a string index declares that
>   obj.property is also available as obj["property"]. In the following
>   example, name’s type does not match the string index’s type, and the
>   type-checker gives an error:
>
> ```
> interface NumberDictionary {
>     [index: string]: number;
>     length: number;    // ok, length is a number
>     name: string;      // error, the type of 'name' is not a subtype of the indexer
> }
> ```