# TypeScript syntax: changes: {[property: string]: SimpleChange }

Tags: angular, typescript

Sorry for the cryptic title but I don't know how to describe this better.

I don't understand this syntax:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: {[property: string]: SimpleChange }) {
```

I have this interpretation:

> A function ngOnChanges accepts a parameter called changes that is of type {[property: string]: SimpleChange }

I do not understand the syntax around `{[property: string]: SimpleChange }`.

If it was just `{property: string}`, I would interpret it as an object with a property called "property" that is of type string.

Could someone, please, explain the syntax to me? It would be kind to provide a reference to the TypeScript docs where this is discussed.

Comment: Relevant: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html

Comment: Or the [official docs: Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)

Comment: @NitzanTomer Thanks, it is now clear to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does this type declaration mean in Typescript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37898424/what-does-this-type-declaration-mean-in-typescript)

Comment: Late to the party but same for me learning Typescript and angular, nothing like I have ever seen before