# Doubts about a typescript syntax found within the documentation

Tags: typescript

I am in reference to the typescript documentation about advanced types. See [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

The following example is given:

```
interface Map<T> {
   [key: string]: T;
}
```

I understand the Map's type variable T.

My doubt is rather about the syntax within the interface declaration i.e. this exact line:

```
[key: string]: T;
```

- Can someone please translate in english what the above line means?
- And refer me to relevant documentation about the square brackets
  syntax for the key?

Comment: I think I have found the answer to my question. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37899294/536299

Comment: Thanks to David Sherret for his reply to the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question. It is a Typescript **Index Signature**.

See following link for a comprehensive explanation: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html